# Spring custom error page instead of tomcat error page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I wonder can we make custom error handler like "Spring Boot Application".

Spring boot application can produce html or json, it's depends what is your accept type.

But I can't make it on spring mvc project. I can only handle exception, not include status error like 415 unsupported media type and just json type.

It's what i'm doing.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Error> allExceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
    Error error = new Error(new Date(), e.getCause().getMessage(), req.getRequestURL().toString());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}

public class Error {

    private Date date;
    private String cause;
    private String url;

    /* Getter Setter */
}
```

I want the error page like that:

[HTML Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odjKO.jpg)

[JSON Error Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdgYv.jpg)